# Change Exchange Account Password

Tags: exchange, accounts

On my Phone (NordPlus 2, Android 12), I have setup an exchange Account which should sync Calendar and Contacts (not mail!) with a 3rd Party Exchange Server.

Some time ago, I changed the password for this Account and recently I discovered that the sync is not working anymore (as expected after the password change).

I would like to activate it again, but I can't find an option to do so.
Settings -> Users and Accounts ->  only shows 3 checkboxes for Mail, Contacts and Calendar and that's it. The Menu there only gives the option to sync now or remove the account.

I do not want to delete and recreate the account, as I would probably loose all events and contacts on the phone associated with this account.

What can I do to solve this?